# How to connect my application with a local server in android

Tags: android

I'm a beginner, and I need to find a way to connect a local server to an android app. I hope you can provide me with a book to teach me hoe to do it. I have searched all over google, but couldn't find any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the link for local connection: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but you're bad looking. First of all, do not forget, those development under the android goes for Java.

This way you can approach [this article](http://syntx.io/a-client-server-application-using-socket-programming-in-java/).

But this question shows a poor level of your knowledge. You should go through a couple of courses [java](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=java) and [android](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=android).

Please learn basic skills. Tutorials "step by step" may leave a gap in your knowledge.